Global coordinate system with 2 cameras
I have a question regarding coordinate transformation (or perhaps registration, not sure what the correct term is).
I have a setup with two top-down cameras: Camera A and Camera B.
Both cameras are in the same space but there is a distance between them, so their FOVs do not overlap. There is a table located on the setup with an object, and the table is attached onto a motor. When the table is positioned underneath the camera A, it has full view of the table and the object, the camera B has a high magnification objective, with which you can view the features of the object itself.
I have calibrated camera A to correct for fisheye distortion, so I have its intrinsic parameters.
My goal is to click on a point in the camera A, with which I retrieve the pixel coordinate, and have the motor move so that the same point is centered under the camera B. I am struggling with how to map coordinates from the camera A to the camera B. No rotations are involved; only translation in XY. Don’t care about Z for now.
I am really not sure how to proceed. I think I need to convert pixel coordinates from camera A to world coordinates by multiplying the point to the inverse of the camera matrix, but then I’m kind of stuck. any direction would be appreciated. I use OpenCV for camera A.
The object is planar.
The motor has its coordinate system relative to reference point
Thanks.

just for chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/258798/coordinate-mapping

The setup confuses me. So you have 2 cameras point downward at different location, the table is covering the FOV of camera A, and when you click at a point, the table then runs to camera B and show the point to the much lower field of camera B right? If that is the case, all you need to do is map both pixel coordinates from the 2 camera to the world coordinates. Camera B has a narrow FOV, so maybe just map the center point of that FOV to the world coordinates, or better, mark that point on the ground using some tapes and work out its world coordinates using a ruler. Now you could get the world coordinates of the point on the table using an inverse transformation, calculate the offset between the 2 points, and control the motor to move the table from the start to the end point.

Hi, yes, the motor has its own coordinate system relative to the reference point which is user-defined, I think I emitted this detail which could be important. I'm confused how you get "world coordinates", what I tried before is that I centered the FOV on camera A on some feature (like the border of the object) and noted its motor coordiantes, then I did the same with camera B with the same feature, but i'm not 100% sure how to correlate that.

Since we appear to give non-code answers to non-code questions today, I'll join in.

Know where your cameras are in the world.

Know where your planes are in the world... such as the plane on which the point lies.

Turn the 2D point into a 3D ray originating from the camera in which it is viewed.

Intersect the ray with the plane on which the 3D point is expected to be.


Now you've got a 3D point, that you can do anything with.
You could now calculate another camera's position such that the 3D point would be projected to a specific 2D point in its view. Of course that'll take a few more constraints to have a unique solution.

Thanks for the answer. I'm not 100% sure what it means to know where the cameras are in the real world. If I position the motor in a way that camera A's FOV centers some distinct feature on the object(lets say thats a calibration point), note its motor coordinates, and then locate the same feature under camera B (in which that feature would be much more prominent due to high magnification) and note the motor coordinates again, I'd have the offset between camera locations, at least in respect to that calibration point, would that not mean I know where the cameras are in the real world? Thanks!

knowing where they are means having their pose matrices, i.e. extrinsics. specifically that is their position and orientation, as a convenient 4x4 matrix. there are many ways to obtain that at various accuracies. you could measure a "world" pose (chessboard or AR marker) in each camera's coordinate frame, and invert that.

what you're doing is robotics, kinematics. that involves a bunch more equations than I have experience with. the literal motor itself is irrelevant. you just need a model of how your camera can move.

Both cameras are at fixed location and are top down, they're not supposed to be moved at all. I assumed I'd not need to calibrate for extrinsic parameters since there are no rotations. So I did chessboard calibration for camera A at fixed distance and with no rotation, just a flat chessboard calibration to get focal length and the principal point & distortion coefficients.

I mean I originally did it for fisheye correction, wasn't sure yet how would it be useful for this particular problem.

ah, so cameras are fixed, and... some work piece is moving? mathematically, that's pretty much the same: the pose between object and camera changes.

Yes, the planar object is placed onto a table that is controlled by the motor. So If I want to see that object through either of the cameras, I have to align the motor beneath the camera appropriately. Given that the motor has pretty precise coordinate position sensors (micron scale), I thought It'd be easier than expected to translate some point from camera A into motor absolute position so the motor aligns the same point under camera B. I never change the position of cameras themselves.
